# How can I automatically run a Gmail filter on existing emails every day?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'd like to automatically archive certain emails if I haven't done it myself after they're, say, a week old. I could use a filter to archive these emails, but I'd have to run the filter myself manually.

Is there a way to automatically run a Gmail filter on existing emails every day?

Comment: Not with Gmail all by itself. Gmail filters only act on messages when they first arrive. You would need to look to a third-party to do what you're looking to do. I don't know of any off-hand, though.

Comment: That's doable with Google Apps Script.

Comment: Here's an [article](http://lifehacker.com/5986204/automatically-clean-up-gmail-on-a-schedule-with-this-script) with a couple of google apps scripts that might do the trick.